# Surfaceview is not creating immidiately after asking for runtime permission

Tags: android, surfaceview, runtime-permissions

I am stuck with this issue of **Surfaceview** and **runtime perssion**,

I have requirement of showing the camera preview using the **Surfaceview** at a main activity, So i am asking for the runtime permission when i call the code to show the camera preview.

But I am initializing the Surfaceview immediately after the permission is granted for camera, At that time the **surfaceCreated()** callback never calls and permission is also granted(I have checked from the Settings).

Once i kill the app and open again it works perfect after that.

Here is my initalising code,

in **MainActivity,**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    initCameraPreview();
}
```

in initCameraPreview() method,

```
public void initCameraPreview(){
    StartCameraPreview preview = new StartCameraPreview(context, surfaceView);

    preview.onCreate();
}
```

I have created on class for SurfaceView,
**StartCameraPreview.java**

```
public StartCameraPreview(Context context, SurfaceView surfaceView) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
}

public void onCreate() {
    if (checkCameraHardware()) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

       // configure preview
        previewHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
}
```

I cannot share much of the code, Sorry.
So i have just added the initalization code.
Did anyone face that issue or any one knows any solution for this?

Please help
Thanks in adv.

Comment: I think you will have to re-initialize the SurfaceView somehow after the permission is granted.

Comment: I am initializing the surfaceview after the permission is granted

Comment: show how you do it

Comment: Okay i am updating my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the visibility of the SurfaceView to INVISIBLE initially and set it to VISIBLE after the permission is granted . This way the drawing surface gets created after the permission result. Hope this helps.